# Ruby: How can I properly use `yield` to pass unnamed code block to Integer#times method?

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby, and for no particular reason, I want to pass the `yield` object to the Integer#times method so that the `yield` code block is called a number of times. Here is how I can do it with a named code block:

```
def withNamedCodeBlock &b
  3.times(&b)
end
withNamedCodeBlock {print "Go "}
#returns Go Go Go
```

Now, I want to do the same, but without named code blocks; I want to do it with by using the `yield` keyword. Here is how I tried and failed:

```
def withYield
  3.times(&yield)
end
withYield {print "Go "}
#returns Go => #<Enumerator: 3:times>
#I expect it to return Go Go Go
```

I am still wrapping my head around the various ways to pass code blocks to methods, so additional information regarding that is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sake of completeness on this topic, I wanted to demonstrate another technique to call the original block:

```
def withProc
  p = Proc.new
  3.times(&p)
end
withProc { print "Go" }
```

When `Proc.new` is not given a block, it uses the block that was given to `withProc` instead. Now you can call `p`, and it will call the original block.  You can also pass `p` to other methods like `times` either as a regular argument or as a block argument.

See https://medium.com/@amliving/proc-new-trick-c1df16185599 for more discussion

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yeah I first learned about it from this talk from AaronPatterson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8m6rY4JI1U&feature=youtu.be&t=1830 or maybe a blog post based off of this talk.

Comment: I remember this blog post: https://mudge.name/2011/01/26/passing-blocks-in-ruby-without-block.html

Comment: wow! This is a great article. Answers the question I didn't know how to ask ;)

Answer (score 4):

> I want to pass the `yield` object to the `Integer#times` method so that the `yield` code block is called a number of times

`yield` is not an object, nor is it a block. It's not even a method call. It's a keyword that *yields* control to a passed block. If you want to do anything else with the block (save it for later, pass it around, etc.), you must name it.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to name the unnamed block within the method?

Comment: @KZcoding you name the block by using a named block argument. Why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: no reason. I am trying to understand that internal details behind these objects and the motivations for using them.

Answer (score 3):

@sergio-tulentsev's answer is good. But, I wanted to point out that you can wrap `yield` in a new block and thereby pass along the ability to yield to the original block:

```
def withYield
  3.times { yield }
end
withYield {print "Go "}
```

To be clear, `{ yield }` is a new block, and it is passed to `times`. When the new block is executed, it yields to the *original* `{ print "Go" }` block that was given to  `withYield`. The original block isn't actually passed to `times`, but the ability to yield to the original block is passed, *effectively* letting you call the original block.

Comment: So this is pretty much what I was looking for. Although, I don't understand why this works. Does the 'times' method internally also call 'yield'?

Comment: @KZcoding yes, it does call `yield` – that's the usual way to call a passed block.

Comment: _"wrap yield in a new block and thereby pass it around"_ – you don't pass the block around. You pass another block and that one calls the outer block.

Comment: @Stefan: if we ignore OP's "I want to pass yield block" (which doesn't make sense) and instead answer the "I want to do it only with yield", then this is a good answer. Does the same thing, side-effect-wise. But no blocks are passed on here, of course. I would probably amend the wording to make that extra-clear.

Comment: related question, what does `&yield` mean?

Comment: @KZcoding: nothing special. It's operator `&` applied to whatever `yield` returns. In this case, it's the same as `&nil`

Comment: @stefan I have reworded my answer. Please feel free to suggest different wording if it still needs clarification.